# Track goals ajax form with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, google-analytics, form-submit

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I have an ajax form on my website and I'm trying to track the signups. I have read multiples post on SO on the subject but cant make it work.

This is a copy of the code of my form: http://pastie.org/1916397
And there is a screenshot of my goal config in Google Analytics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2TX5.png

I have signups, but Google Analytics dont seem to detect them ! :(

I have that Google Analytics tag on my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Thank you by advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pastie:

```
<input class="submit-element" type="submit" name="contact" value="Signup!" onlick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/outgoing/button-click']);" />
```

Unless you're triggering an event when a user *licks* a form, the problem is that your attribute is misspelled. It should be `onclick`, not `onlick`.

Happens to the best of us :)